# Questions on Augmenting path (Ford-Fulkerson method)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I'm learning the Ford-Fulkerson method nowadays.

Some articles say 
If f is a maximum flow, then there's no augmenting path!
**But if there's no augmenting path, how do you know f is maximum flow?**

- How do you know the way finding augmenting path is correct?
- In the residual network, why if we can't reach t from s there is no way to increase flow? How do you know that?

Comment: I think you have a slight misunderstanding on what augmenting paths are & where they fit in this algorithm. They are an intermediate representation that includes a "subset" of the final flow. You recursively find new aug. paths & add them up, slowly increasing your capacity to the max. Once there is no way of increasing it, thats because you are at capacity, thus you have the max flow & there are no augmenting paths a.k.a no way of reaching t from s. The last question can be proved by contradiction. If there was a way of reaching t from s, there would be a aug. path & thus a way of reaching t.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Max-flow min-cut theorem, cf. e.g. Theorem 26.6 in [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). The gist is the following: Let *S* be the set of vertices accessible from the source in the residual network, and let *T* = *V* \ *S*. Then, if there are no augmenting paths, (*S*, *T*) is a cut, and one finds that the value of the flow is the capacity of this cut. Since flow values can never exceed cut capacities, it follows that the flow is maximal.